# Advice needed on packaging dynamic dashboards

Tags: managed-package, limits, dashboard

Our build just broke with this error when we added a 4th dynamic dashboard:

> You reached the limit for dashboards run as the logged-in user

and articles like this one [Increase 'Maximum Number of Dynamic Dashboards' limit](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000336671&type=1) indicate why:

> This defines the limit on Dynamic Dashboards permitted for use within
> the environment, based on the organization edition.
>
> The following are the default values:
>
> - Enterprise Edition: up to 5 per organization.
> - Performance and Unlimited Edition: up to 10 per organization.
> - Developer Edition: up to 3 per organization.

as our `project-scratch-def.json` specifies `"edition": "Developer"`.

But this begs the question of what happens when the org the managed package is installed into **already has dynamic dashboards set up so the limit is exceeded**? A failed install? Is including *any* of these in a managed package therefore an anti-pattern?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ...what happens when the org the managed package is installed into already has dynamic dashboards set up so the limit is exceeded? A failed install?

Yep. It can also fail push upgrades for extra confusion if both you and the subscriber have created dynamic dashboards.

> Is including any of these in a managed package therefore an anti-pattern?

Yep. Because the dynamic dashboard limit is not namespace-scoped, including them in a managed package is an anti-pattern unless you control all of the environments in which the package will be installed. If necessary, deliver the dynamic dashboards in a separate extension package that subscribers can choose to install or not install.

Comment: Thanks David; very helpful.

Comment: Thanks David. This crazy! I'm using Dashboard for an App usage stats. 

Might see if the installer can toggle an existing to specific person to install, then post install toggle ours to specific person and revert their dashboard back.